# Using twig attributes like asset not working in jQuery with placeholder values

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, twig

I am trying to change the picture when I submit ajax on success through changing the `src` of the `img` tag. I get this error though:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/%7B%7B%20asset('/uploads/images/$%7Bdata.picSource%7D')%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

I also get errors in creating new buttons with jQuery that has twig `path` in their `href` atrributes. I have read the articles about putting the twig part in such quotes:"", but I use these: `` and inside of them "" in order to put variables freely in the `path` to make it dynamic.
This is my ajax query:

```
$(".uploadPic").on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/upload",
        data: new FormData($(".uploadPic")[0]),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            let newSource = `"{{ asset('/uploads/images/${data.picSource}')}}"`;
            $("#userPic").attr('src', newSource);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

The response in the network tab is normal(the name and extension of the picture): {"picSource":"8bcfb2d2a1117cbb452f632829a5cad8.jpeg"}, but I get error from passing the new attribute. 
The part from the controller on successfull ajax request:

```
if(isset($request->request)) {

        $file = $request->files->get('user_pic_type')['userPic'];
        $file = $user->getUserPic();
        $fileName = $this->generateUniqueFileName() . '.' . $file->guessExtension();


        $file->move(
            $this->getParameter('users_directory'),
            $fileName
        );

        $user->setUserPic($fileName);


        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();


        return new JsonResponse(array('picSource' => $fileName));

    }
```

What I can do to correct this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mixed up JS (which runs in your browser) and PHP (which runs on your server and transmits rendered HTML to the browser). If you want to generate such an asset rule in the frontend, you should either fire an AJAX call for it or generate the URL by hand.

But as you already use an AJAX call, you should use it to return the image path for you. Add some code like this to your PHP controller:

```
 /** @var \Symfony\Component\Asset\Packages $manager */
$manager = $this->get('assets.packages');
$imagePath = $manager->getUrl('/uploads/images/' . $fileName);

return new JsonResponse(array('picSource' => $fileName, 'imagePath' => $imagePath));
```

Now, the backend already generates all neccessary data for you and sends it to the browser